# Best memory settings for eclipse 4.2 (STS 3.1) on Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: eclipse, performance, spring

I apoligize in advance if this question is indeed too subjective as SO warns me.

My workstation has 8 gb of ram and runs windows 7 64 bit. I use the Spring tool Suite (3.1) but as soon as i am starting to open and modify the spring config (.xml) files, STS becomes incredibly slow.

I already tried switching off "build automatically" and to increase memory settings but no luck.

How should i change my .ini ? this is what i have set now:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
4096M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

My collageu running the same project in IntelliJ, has no problems.

Thank you!

Comment: Might be usefull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse in addition i would start by reducing the value off --launcher.XXMaxPermSize to 256M ...

Comment: I did, didn't help. Went for intelliJ as my IDE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2gb heap is plenty for eclipse, I use it myself.  My suspicion is the culprit is Eclipse 4.2 Juno.  It has very well documented [performance issues](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272).  There is a hidden 3.8 Juno version on the [eclipse download site](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/eclipse3x.html).  It has all the same features that 4.2 Juno has but uses the old UI components which are more stable and performant.

Answer (score 2):

```
After doing lot of research , this arguments solves my problem

-nosplash
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
#/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java #OS X
-vmargs
-Xincgc
-Xss1m
-Duser.name=FirstName LastName
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Declipse.p2.MD5Check=false
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:NewSize=16m
-XX:PermSize=128m
-XX:MaxPermSize=400m
-XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=20m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
-XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=2
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0
-XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5
-XX:GCTimeRatio=49
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=1000
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+AggressiveOpts #Doesnt work with Android see Google Code Android issue 9883
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses
-Xverify:none
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JC7B1a_7dQ This is a good guide on optimal performance for eclipse and android